# Strong-pm.log file is Empty

Tags: node.js, unix, logging, strongloop

Strong-pm.log file in `/var/log` folder is empty.
After deploying API to VM we are not able to see any logs in Strong-pm.log.
Even deployment errors and others logging are not workingin Strong-pm.log.
Can someone help me on this

Comment: What are you using? What is the configuration?

Comment: We have developed a Strongloop framework based api and we have deployed the Tar file in one of the VM. Earlier all logs are working fine now since past few weeks strong-pm.log is not working

Comment: Can you release some of the logging code? Like, what all does it show? Any internal logs? Anything

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
My log location is changed from /var/log to /var/log/strongloop .

Does anyone know where we can mention the path for stron-pm.log ?